# When Intel/AMD plan to use new CPU sockets?

Tags: central-processing-unit

It is very expensive always to use most modern hardware especially buying new mainboard if only a new CPU is desired. It would be much better if one knows whether and when major CPU producers plan to change CPU sockets. Do you know when it is planed to change sockets the next time? I am particularly interested in not buying Intel i7 CPU if a new CPU will be released soon with not compatible pins.

Comment: I think you'd have more luck with this on SuperUser, or some hardware site.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

At the moment Intel is not planning any new CPU sockets, basing on their CPU plans.
Latest socket is µPGA-989 and new (coming in 2010) Core i7-6xxM with integrated GPU will use it. This means that at moment Intel is focusing on mobile platforms.

If you are planning to assembly a desktop machine with extra horsepower, I'd recommend LGA1366. For mobile go µPGA-989.

Info on Intel's i7 CPU family is [here](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Intel_Core_i7) and [here](http://www.intel.com/products/processor/corei7/specifications.htm). Also, interesting info about Intel plans change, [here](http://theovalich.wordpress.com/2009/01/31/exclusive-intels-cans-45nm-auburndale-and-havendale-fusion-cpus/).